# Java/Quarkus: How to Inject different instances which return the same data type

Tags: java, rest, dependency-injection, quarkus, inject

I am in a bit tricky situation where I have 2 methods in my Quarkus `RESTApplication` both of which return the same data type. However, I would like to inject them into 2 different variables.

If there is only one method with one variable then everything works fine but since there are 2 methods and both of which return the same type the Quarkus is unable to identify which to inject and runs into the error:

```
Ambiguous dependencies for type String and qualifiers [@Default]
```

Following is my code:
RestApplication.class, this has the @Produces which will provide the required dependency:

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class RESTApplication extends Application {

    @Produces
    public String firstMethod() {
        System.out.println("firstMethod : returns Hello One");
        return "HELLO ONE";
    }

    @Produces
    public String secondMethod() {
        System.out.println("secondMethod : returns Hello TWO");
        return "HELLO TWO";
    }
}
```

Following is the class where I am injecting the returned value:

```
@Path("/api")
public class RestAPI {

    @Inject
    String one;

    @Inject
    String two;

    @Path("/one")
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String myMethodOne(final String input) {
        System.out.println("One : " + one)
        return one;
    }

    @Path("/two")
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String myMethodOne(final String input) {
        System.out.println("Two : " + two)
        return two;
    }
}
```

As you can see both methods are returning the same type so Quarkus cannot understand which one to inject. Is there a way to differentiate this?

If I remove the second method in `RestApplication` then everything works perfectly. In my project, I need to return different values of the same type based on some calculation so I need to use something like this.

Comment: You can use qualifiers to distinguish them: https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi#you-talked-about-some-qualifiers

Comment: @Ladicek please add that as answer for the benefit of future readers

Answer (score 0):

Based on the OP's code, as to not be overly long.

Java:

```
@Qualifier // Create Qualifier annotation
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE})
public @interface Blah {}

...

@Produces
@Blah // Add it
public String firstMethod() {

...

@Inject
@Blah // Qualify it
String one;
```

Kotlin:

```
@Qualifier // Create Qualifier annotation
@Retention
@Target(AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY, AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION, AnnotationTarget.FIELD, AnnotationTarget.CLASS, AnnotationTarget.VALUE_PARAMETER) // Not all are needed
annotation class Blah

...

@Produces
@Blah // Add it
fun firstMethod(): String {

...

// As a constructor parameter
class RestAPI(@Blah private val one: String) {

// OR as a field
@Inject
@field:Blah
lateinit var one: String
```